# Delete an item from a C# collections List object

Tags: c#, list

In my C# project , I am using a `Hashtable`, but it is not able to store more than one value with same key. So I changed it to use `List`. I am getting data from sql and loading the `List`. After loading data I want to remove items from list based on an id. How can I make it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`List<T>.RemoveAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx) method, which takes a `Predicate<T>` as an argument.

For example, if you wanted to remove all items with an `Id` of `5`, you could do:

```
int numRemoved = list.RemoveAll(x => x.Id == 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try linq on your `List<T>`.

```
yourList.RemoveAll(item => item.Id == yourKey);
```

Assuming you are storing items that have a field to compare against.

MSDN link for reference to `RemoveAll`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx